# Set Default Browser Using Command Prompt on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, batch-file, cmd.exe, default-settings

This command no longer works:

> chrome.exe --make-default-browser

How can I change the default browser via command line in Windows 10

Comment: Is it need to be done using command or you need to make chrome the default browser?

Comment: Your machine is in domain or work group?

Answer (score 4):

Powershell commands

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\https\UserChoice' -Name ProgId -Value 'ChromeHTML'
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\http\UserChoice' -Name ProgId -Value 'ChromeHTML'
```

Comment: This won't work on Windows 10. As hash validation is in place, writing to `UserChoice` directly causes [An App Default was Reset](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/windows-10-resetting-file-associations/) issue in Windows 10.

Comment: Chrome still shows "Set as default" button on start.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple way. Here is the official guidance - it includes creating pre-configuration XML and applying group policies:
https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7009292?hl=en

Also, a developer created a small helper to achieve it:
https://github.com/sampalmer/set-default-browser