# Powershell to set Chrome as default browser

Tags: google-chrome, browser, powershell

I been searching for a couple of day now to set this.

```
    Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

    ; Set IE as default & associate CSS / HTM / HTML with Notepad Plus
    ; Made for Windows 7

 [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.mht\UserChoice]
"Progid"="IE.AssocFile.MHT"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.mhtml\UserChoice]
"Progid"="IE.AssocFile.MHT"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.url\UserChoice]
"Progid"="IE.AssocFile.URL"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\http\UserChoice]
"Progid"="IE.HTTP"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\https\UserChoice]
"Progid"="IE.HTTPS"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\ftp\UserChoice]
"Progid"="IE.FTP"


;Associate CSS / HTM / HTML with Notepad Plus

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.CSS]
@="Notepad++"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.HTM]
@="Notepad++"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.HTML]
@="Notepad++"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Notepad++\shell\open\command]
@="d:\\Tools\\NPP\\notepad++.exe \"%1\""

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.css]

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.htm]

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.html]
<code>
```

I have tried to do it through the registry. **Failed**

```
$Path = $env:TEMP; $Installer = "chrome_installer.exe"; Invoke-WebRequest 
"http://dl.google.com/chrome/install/3..." -OutFile $Path\$Installer; Start-Process -FilePath
$Path\$Installer -Args "/silent /install" -Verb RunAs -Wait; Remove-Item $Path\$Installer

$chromePath = "${Env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Google\Chrome\Application\" 
$chromeApp = "chrome.exe"
$chromeCommandArgs = "--make-default-browser"
& "$chromePath$chromeApp" $chromeCommandArgs
```

I have tried the above script.  **Failed**

I have also tried the --make-default-browser.  **Failed**

I have tried to do this through GPO.  **Failed**

how do I make windows 10 through Power shell to  set the default browser to Google Chrome

The above other question give me this output
[image: PowerShell Chrome error]

Comment: Please expand on what you mean by the failures in each of these cases. What is the current default browser? What are the symptoms of failure?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cmd command to set Chrome as default browser Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1223126/cmd-command-to-set-chrome-as-default-browser-windows-10)

Comment: music2myear - I tried that link.  By Failed i mean it didn't set Chrome as the default browser.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to manipulate browser settings via the registry, consider using the OS to assign file types with executables. Normally I'd rather stay in PSH to do things... but I do know that you could associate file types to Chrome using CMD's `assoc` and `ftype` commands.

If there is a PSH way to do this, I don't know it. If someone reading this knows how in PSH, please comment. I'd be curious.

from PSH, call them [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33571900/assoc-and-ftype-do-not-work-under-powershell):

```
cmd /c assoc
cmd /c ftype
```

- Open an elevated command prompt.
- Use `FTYPE {fileType}={commandString}` to create a file type and associated command to open the file.
- Use `ASSOC {.fileExtension}={fileType}`

For example:

```
cmd /c assoc .txt=txtfile
cmd /c ftype txtfile=c:\Program Files\Windows NT\Accessories\wordpad.exe "%1"
```

For more information, please refer to:

[Associate a File Type with a Specific Program](http://superuser.com/questions/29717/associate-a-file-type-with-a-specific-program)

[Source](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/06d35f90-56cb-4dec-b326-bd471d06acee/change-default-program-for-file-command-line-or-registry)

Comment: Here is what i wrote
   cmd /c assoc .htm=htmfile
   cmd /c ftype htmfile="C:\Program Files 
   (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "%1"

   cmd /c assoc .html=htmlfile
   cmd /c ftype htmlfile="C:\Program Files 
   (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "%1"
Here is the result
.htm=htmfile
File type 'htmfile=C:\Program Files' not found or no open command associated with it.
.html=htmlfile
File type 'htmlfile=C:\Program Files' not found or no open command associated with it.